# IIS Manager: What is the Time Elapsed UOM when examining an IIS Worker process?

Tags: iis-7

OK, this has to be msec, but in some docs it is sometimes mentioned as seconds.

Thoughts?

(UOM is units of measure, e.g. "seconds" or "milliseconds" or whatever)

[image: screen shot of IIS Manager]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is milliseconds.

The output of this command shows msec as unit:

```
appcmd list requests /elapsed:100

REQUEST "b00000008000005d" (url:GET /test.aspx, time:359 **msec**, client:localhost, stage: ExecuteRequestHandler, module:IsapiModule)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, and I can't vouch for the current answer's accuracy for older versions of IIS, but the question is still relevant and answers are still pretty much non-existent, so here is an update.

For current versions of IIS (my reference is version 10.0), this value represents *microseconds*.

I've scoured the IIS and Microsoft documentation trying to find this, but they don't qualify the field and only say it's the time taken (thanks Microsoft - see link below).

However, my proof that it's microseconds is simply in the larger values I've observed, like 1424469, which is possible as microseconds (1.42 seconds), but not as milliseconds (23.74 minutes).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732518(v=ws.10)

Comment: Can confirm this updated answer.